# Adding document and subcollection to a collection - firestore python

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

We have a collection in Google Firestore.

Can we add a document with data and a subcollection under this new document in one statement?

Answer (score 1):

In one *statement*, no.  Strictly speaking, most programming languages are going to require at least one statement for each document to write using the provided APIs.

In one batch, yes.  You can simply do a [batch write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to create any two documents simultaneously.  Parent documents and subcollections do not need to exist in order to create a nested document, so there is not even any requirement to create the parent document, if that's what you were wondering.

Also, you can't create a subcollection that doesn't "exist".  It will exist when the first document is written, and disappear when the last document is deleted.